# How to make one rest endpoint accessible without any security , while having spring-security implemented in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

I need to make one rest endpoint available globally without any authentication, based on the response of the first service will prepare token and will based for authentication for the second service. As having spring-security, application always asks to implement the BASIC or FORM login, i don't have this use case in my application.

Even i have this route in websecurityconfig to PERMITALL, still need some authentication to contact the application

```
 http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/v1/test").permitAll()
.anyRequest().authenticated(;
```

Comment: @AA_PV, expecting your answer on this

Comment: Without your code implementation, it is impossible to provide an answer

Comment: how did you permit the route? Add some code pls

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya please see the code updated

Comment: @Spara Please see the code updated

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you can share your code, here is the code configuring spring security. 
In following code: antMatchers with permitAll are accessible without authentication and antMatchers with role ROLE_USER are accessible after user logs in.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/user/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .and()
        .formLogin()    
            .loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard")    
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")  
            .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/403");
}
```

Comment: will the /home be accessed without any authentication?

Comment: Yes /, home and /user/register all are accessible without any authentication